# pointer arithmetic on arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When I run the code below my output is not what I expect.

My way of understanding it is that `ptr` points to the address of the first element of the `Str` array. I think `ptr + 5` should lead to the + 5th element which is `f`. So the output should only display `f` and not both `fg`.

Why is it showing `fg`? Does it have to do with how `cout` displays an array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    char Str[] = "abcdefg";

    ptr = Str;
    ptr += 5;

    cout << ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: `f`

Actual output: `fg`

Comment: ptr - pointer to string. If you want to print char, use *ptr: cout << *ptr;

Comment: Replace "lead" with more appropriate "point to" and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare:

```
char Str[] = "abcdefg"
```

The string `abcdefg` is stored implicitly with an extra character `\0` which marks the end of the string.

So, when you `cout` a `char*` the output will be all the characters stored where the `char *` points and all the characters stored in consecutive memory locations after the `char*` until a `\0` character is encountered at one of the memory locations! Since, `\0` character is after `g` in your example hence 2 characters are printed.

In case you only want to print the current character, you shall do this ::

```
cout << *ptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it showing `fg`?

The reason why `std::cout << char*` prints the string till the end instead of a single char of the string is , because `std::cout` treats a `char *` as a pointer to the first character of a C-style string and prints it as such.<sup>1</sup>

Your array:

```
char Str[] = "abcdefg";
```

gets implicitly assigned an `'\0'`at the end and it is treated as a C-style string.

> Does it have to do with how `std::cout` displays an array?

This has to do with how `std::cout` handles [C-style strings](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/), to test this change the array type to `int` and see the difference, i.e. it will print a single element.

---

<sup>1. This is because in C there are no string types and strings are manipulated through pointers of type `char`, indicating the beginning and termination character: `'\0'`, indicating the end.</sup>